# In Which table Product image url stored in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

I want to find Product image url stored location in Prestashop Database.

Comment: Its database schema is documented and publicly available for download.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Product image urls are not stored in database. The location is based on the `id_image` field of `ps_image` table.

An image having `1234` for id will be stored under `/img/p/1/2/3/4/1234.jpg`.

An image having `1514` for id will be stored under `/img/p/1/5/1/4/1514.jpg`.

I invite you to check `/classes/Image.php` and `/classes/ImageManager.php` for more informations.

Comment: not quite -- an image having `1234` for id will be stored under `/img/p/1/2/3/4/1234.jpg`.

Answer (score 4):

As told by Floarian images are stored in `{DB_PREFIX}image` table and located in `img/p` folder based on id of the image.

If you have moved images as per new system, your images are located as told by Floarian but url of image will be like..

> {YOUR_SITE_URL}/img/p/{ID_IMAGE}-{IMAGE_TYPE}/{FRIENDLY_URL_OF_PRODUCT}.jpg

e.g.

> www.testsite.com/img/p/1234-home_default/my-test-product.jpg

Comment: interesting detail

Comment: not exactly -- the `img/p/` section of URI is not needed and will not resolve.  `www.site.com/1234-home_default/my-test-product.jpg`

Comment: It is exactly like this @zzzaaabbb in prestashop v 1..6... Check this https://livedemo00.template-help.com/free_prestashop_1_6_template/img/p/3/1/31-home_default.jpg

Comment: It would be like www.testsite.com/img/p/1/2/3/4/1234-home_default/my-test-product.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As stated in earlier answers, the URL of the images is built using the `id_image` field (stored in `ps_image` table) related to a given product.

Here is a (simplified) SQL query to retrieve `id_image` value for each product:

```sql
SELECT ps_product.id_product, ps_image.id_image 
FROM ps_product, ps_image
WHERE ps_image.id_product = ps_product.id_product AND ps_image.position = 1
```

And here is how to build related URLs :

```php
// [...] run SQL query and fetch an array of resulting rows
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $url = '/img/p/'.implode('/', str_split((string) $row[1])).'/'.$row[1].'.jpg';
}
```

Hope this helps ...